# How to understand this async/await exercise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

I am doing some exercises on `async/await` and I am completely blank on this one:

> The `​​opA`​ function must be called before ​`opB`​, and ​`opB​` must be
> called before `​opC`​. Call functions such a way
> that `​C`​ then `​B`​ then `​A`​ is printed out.

```
const print = (err, contents) => {
  if (err) console.error(err)
  else console.log(contents )
}

const opA = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'A')
  }, 500)
}

const opB = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'B')
  }, 250)
}

const opC = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'C')
  }, 125)
}
```

My guess is there is a typo in the question, so I should just have the functions print out `A B C` and not `C B A`?

**My attempt is this:**

```
(async function () {
  await print(opA());
  await print(opB());
  await print(opC());
}());
```

but I get

```
    cb(null, 'C')
    ^

TypeError: cb is not a function
```

**Question**

I have literally no idea how to solve this one, and don't understand the usage of the `print` function.

Any help on how to get me going will be much appreciated =)

Comment: can you change the functions at all, currently none of your code supports async/await

Comment: This is not an `async/await` exercise.  Functions are asynchronous but not `async` functions.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async/await` or `promises`. All the functions have a variable called `cb` which is a callback function. For example `opA(print)` would call `opA` and `opA` would call `print(null, 'A')` after a timeout of 0.5 seconds. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said this is an async/await exercise but the code you show is the complete antithesis of async/await - it uses the callback paradigm.

To make your code print `C B A` you would need to pass callbacks to the `opX` functions in such an order to make them print their results:

```js
const print = (err, contents) => {
  if (err) console.error(err)
  else console.log(contents )
}

const opA = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'A')
  }, 500)
}

const opB = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'B')
  }, 250)
}

const opC = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'C')
  }, 125)
}

opA(print);
opB(print);
opC(print);
```

Answer (score 2):

The function stored in `optA`, `opB`, `opC` accept a callback function `cb` that is called in the timeout, with the first argument set to `null` and the second to `A`, `B`, `C`.

`print` holds a function that accepts an error (`err`) as first argument and the thing to print as the second argument (`contents`).

So you would combine the `opt` function with `print` that way: `optA(print)`.

In the current form of the question, it would just be:

```
opA(print)
opB(print)
opC(print)
```

```js
const print = (err, contents) => {
  if (err) console.error(err)
  else console.log(contents )
}

const opA = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'A')
  }, 500)
}

const opB = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'B')
  }, 250)
}

const opC = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'C')
  }, 125)
}

opA(print)
opB(print)
opC(print)
```

To get the result: `C`, `B`, `A` (due to the delays used for the `setTimeouts`).

But there might be something missing in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which you call these functions is almost irrelevant for the desired result. The timers are set to run in that specific order, first `C`, then `B` then `A`.

So you can just call them:

```
opA(print);
opB(print);
opC(print);
```

Or even:

```
opB(print);
opA(print);
opC(print);
```

Or even:

```
opC(print);
opB(print);
opA(print);
```

However, there are ways in which you can switch the order in which would give you a wrong result. For example:

```
opA((err, a) => (
   print(err, a),
   opB((err,b) => (
       print(err, b),
       opC(print)
   ))
))
```

Which will call `opB` after the timer set by `opA` is ran and `opC` is also called after `opB` timer is ran.

I believe the purpose of the exercise might be so you can observe that the order in which you call your functions doesn't always reflect the order you might intuitively expect.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very simliar to a lab exercise that I have spent some time with. Below are three solutions.

*Note, that in the lab, the `promisfy` module is included in the prompt; however, the callback solution, the first solution, doesn't need promsify at all.*

### First, the code prompt:

```
'use strict'
const { promisify } = require('util')

const print = (err, contents) => {
  if (err) console.error(err)
  else console.log(contents)
}

const opA = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'A')
  }, 500)
}

const opB = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'B')
  }, 250)
}

const opC = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'C')
  }, 125)
}
```

The instructions say that "A then B then C [must be] printed out", specifically in that order. Of course, simply calling each function by passing it the `print` callback, prints them in the exact wrong order (due to the cleverly crafted timeouts).

## Solutions

### Solution 1, Callbacks

The first solution focuses on providing a callback other than the `print()` callback function. It is easy to call `opA(print)`, and that works...if you want these to run in parallel.

To run these in series, in a given order, synchronously, each will have to complete before the next. To accomplish this, craft a slightly more complex callback, like this:

```
opA((err, out) => {
  // opA() completed...pass opA output to print()
  print(err, out)

  // now call opB() from within the opA() callback
  opB((err, out) => {

    // opB() completed...pass the opB output to print()
    print(err, out)

    // etc...
    opC((err, out) => {
      print(err, out)
    })
  })
})
```

### Solution 2, Promises with Then/Catch

The second and third solutions make use of the `promisfy` module.

Solution 2 uses `then` and `catch`. For the purposes of simplifying the solution, we can omit `catch()` (however, it is not recommended to omit the catch in a production application).

In my opinion, promisfying the functions to use `then`/`catch` overcomplicates the otherwise simple callback solution (solution 1). Invariably, both solution 1 and solution 2 are their own private, *callback hell*.

```
const a = promisify(opA);
const b = promisify(opB);
const c = promisify(opC);

a()
  .then((out)=> {

    // just like the callback solution
    // we wait in this `then` to call `print`
    print(null, out)

    // and just like in the callback solution
    // now we nest another layer of callback hell
    b()
      .then((out)=> {
        print(null, out)

        // etc...
        c()
          .then((out)=> {
             print(null, out)
          })
      })
  })
```

### Solution 3, Promises with Async/Await

Solution 3 is the most modern and flexible. It implements `async` and `await`.

*Note: the two variables returned by opA(), opB(), and opC() are destructured into the variables `err` and `out` by these statements: `[err, out] = await a()`.*

```
const a = promisify(opA);
const b = promisify(opB);
const c = promisify(opC);

const main = async () => {

  let [err, out] = await a();
  print(err, out);

  [err, out] = await b();
  print(err, out);

  [err, out] = await c();
  print(err, out);
}
main();
```